# Add function to class M2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to add a new function to the \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped class

in \USR\GroupedByCore\etc\di.xml I have

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">  

    <preference for="\Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped"
            type="\USR\GroupedByCore\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" />
</config>
```

in \USR\GroupedByCore\Model\Product\Type\Grouped.php

```
<?php 
namespace USR\GroupedByCore\Model\Product\Type;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped    
{   

    public function getAssociatedProductsByCore($product,$core)
    {

        return "Something";
    }

 }
?>
```

I'm calling it this way in Magento_GroupedProdcut\templates\product\view\type\grouped.p‌​html

```
<?php echo "This should be something: " . $this->getAssociatedProductsByCore($_product,'6'); ?>
```

Its not returning anything at all.  The results is merely "This should be something:".

Comment: From where you try to call, write more detail.

Comment: Magento_GroupedProdcut\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I needed to call it like this:

```
$this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProductsByCore($_product, 6);
```